# Check if two strings start with the same character

Tags: php, string, oop

I'm trying to do this in Object Oriented PHP, but I have an issue when recursion is used (if the first string starts with a "(", I want to check the following char), the other cases work. Here is the code:

```
public static function different_first($item,$item1) {
    if (substr($item, 0, 1) != substr($item1, 0, 1)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else if (substr($item,0,1)=="(") {
        Object::different_first(substr($item, 1), $item1);
    } else { 
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing the return as Mark mentioned. I made a few improvements to your code. This would run a lot faster.

```
public static function different_first($item,$item1) {
    if ($item{0} == $item1{0}){
        return false;
    }elseif ($item{0}=="(") {
        return Object::different_first($item{1}, $item1);
    } else { 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Is the substring function so slow?

Comment: yeh. I dont have the exact benchmarks but this would definitely be faster and is a lot more cleaner.

Comment: I've edited your code because true and false where swapped ;)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a return:

```
return Object::different_first(substr($item, 1), $item1);
```

Comment: Your example case returns `TRUE` for me.. what is the expected result?

Comment: @Shafee right, I don't know what I was looking at, it works :D